# Почему некорректное преобразование цвета?

Tags: python, opencv, цвета, rgb

У меня есть картинка с красным яблоком на столе. При конвертации в HSV получается далеко не исходная картинка. Я слышал, что исходный формат цвета в сv2 - BGR, поэтому попробовал и через BGR и через RGB, но результат всё равно, не тот, что я ожидал.

Ожидаемый мной результат: идентичная исходнику картинка.

Я допустил ошибку в написании кода или полученный мной результат является верным?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("imgs/apple.jpg")

rgb_to_hsv_apple = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
bgr_to_hsv_apple = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("RGB2HSV", rgb_to_hsv_apple)
cv2.imshow("BGR2HSV", bgr_to_hsv_apple)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция `cv2.imshow()` ожидает на вход картинку в формате BGR, поэтому если передать ей каринку в другом формате, то не стоит ожидать нормального отображения.

Следовательно, чтобы нарисовать на экране картинку в формате HSV её необходимо сначала преобразовать в BGR (родной для OpenCV формат):

```
image = cv2.imread("apple.jpg")

bgr_to_hsv_apple = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imshow("", cv2.cvtColor(bgr_to_hsv_apple, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!